# Submitting a successful POST request to the users/:id/retweets end point

Tags: perl, twitter

I've recently been playing with the Twitter API using the Twitter::API module (in beta for v2 of the API) in Perl.

I've got get requests working, no problem. However, now I need to get posts working as well and it's not entirely clear to me how to do this in the documentation at https://metacpan.org/pod/Twitter::API.

Best progress I've made so far is using the following:

```
$client->post
        (
            'users/:id/retweets',
            {
                id => $userId,
                tweet_id => $id,
            },
        );
```

This gets me 'Requests with bodies must have content-type of application/json. at /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0/Twitter/API.pm line 369'

I can see content_type is set in the client headers section:

```
'headers' => {
                                'content_type' => 'application/json;charset=utf8',
                                'accept' => 'application/json',
                                'user_agent' => 'Twitter-API/1.0006 (Perl)',
                                'x_twitter_client' => 'Twitter-API/1.0006 (Perl)',
                                'x_twitter_client_url' => 'https://github.com/semifor/Twitter-API',
                                'x_twitter_client_version' => '1.0006'
                              },
```

I tried to add content-type in there as well with value 'application/json' but this made no difference.

If I remove the 'tweet_id' value then I get:

> 'The `tweet_id` field in the request body can not be empty at /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0/Twitter/API.pm line 369'

The tweet_id is supposed to be set in the body of the request as per: https://www.postman.com/twitter/workspace/twitter-s-public-workspace/request/9956214-3ae30a68-4f8b-430e-8e46-cc5eeb44818d but I'm struggling to set this value correctly.

Grateful for insight and direction.

Comment: I've just requested extended access to API v1.1 and I'm using that in the mean time.

Comment: For what it's worth, I find these very light skins of APIs to not add value to what I'm doing, so I just make the calls myself without the modules.

Answer (score -1):

I realize this answer comes very late, but hopefully it will be useful to someone:

Seems to me `-to_json` option is needed, so, something along the lines of:

```
$client->post(
  'users/:id/retweets',
  {
    -to_json => { 
      id => $userId,
      tweet_id => $id,
    }
  }
);
```